# Labels for general personal information. Essential or not?

Tags: users, labels, text, information

[image]

Is it necessary to provide labels mentioned in the picture. I mean for user these are quite self-explanatory. Any suggestions?

Comment: *is it* quite self explanatory? The date could be 'registered date' or 'date last logged in'. 'Single' could refer to groups, 'single member' vs 'group member'... Let me phrase it another way - what benefit is there to removing the labels?

Comment: @JonW Yes you are absolutely right. Date would require a label but due to lack of space , I was just thinking that I could remove some labels. Or maybe replace them with icons

Comment: To be honest, I don't think changing out the labels for anything would be a guarantee of saving space. You still need to have that row, and the row above it could easily end up longer than the data below. What if someone has the name '[Kiefer William Frederick Dempsey George Rufus Sutherland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiefer_Sutherland)'?

Comment: Yes @JonW  I get your point now !!! Thats a pretty big name though :)

Comment: My point is really that the length of the persons name is a variable, not fixed length field. It is an unknown length, so trying to save space in the row below may be a misnomer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screen appears to be from a Matrimony or Dating website. The labels are important as they give clear understanding of the information.

Your labels can be replaced by icons to save space and eliminate text reading -

[image]

Comment: The trouble with these icons is that, for me at least, I'd first think 'I wonder what that icon means', so I'd hover over it so that I can see the alt-text.

Comment: @JonW Depends on the target users. Generally, the users of such sites are more or less aware of these icons.